# Is there a way to save a baked cloth simulation (in .blend file or to disc)?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, cloth-simulation

Is there a way to save a baked cloth simulation (in .blend file or to disc)? seams odd if you have to bake each time the blend file is reopened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the file first, cache your simulation with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. then use **Current Cache to Bake**. Then use the **Disk Cache** option on Cloth Cache and save again:

[image]

Next time you open the file the cloth simulation will be there.

On the folder where the file is saved you'll see a new folder called blendcache_filename. If you move the blend file to a new location make sure yo move the blendcache folder to the same location.

Comment: ooh, how did I miss that? thx!