# How do you share a blender.file?

Tags: rendering

I am new to blender and have been working on a project that displays "fire" in texture but doesn't show up in render and so, I need to "share the project with others by making it a downloadable link like on youtube" in order for me to solve the problem with insight and knowledge from others because I would like to finish this project simply because I spent too much time on this project haha so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you need a method to share a file across the internet? or is something else wrong? a blend file can contain everything that's needed in a project, it requires no additional files. if you are using libraries, which I doubt, you can zip those.

Comment: Thank you for your response and yes, that's exactly what I want/need to do! How do I make the file downloadable (as a link, to be exact) like how people release their models to the public on youtube with tutorials for downloading because I feel like other blender users would have to look at it because my knowledge is limited being that I just started and so I wouldn't be able to answer what the more technical user would probably expect me to know.

Answer (score 4):

Before uploading make sure to **pack** all external data.

Images used as textures, backgrounds or environments do not get saved into the .blend file by default. To include those as part of the file you have to [**Pack**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/introduction.html#pack-unpack-data) them. In the File menu press File>External Data>"Pack all into .blend"

[image]

PLEASE NOTE:

**Image sequences, video files and Simulations Cache Folders will not be packed**. For those it would be better to place them in a common folder along with the blend file and zip them (or bundle them with any other packaging software). And share the whole folder. For convenience you might also want to make the blend file work with [**relative paths**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/relative_paths.html), so that you don't have to re-create the folder structure used on the original computer.

For more info, read this page form the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/info/file.html?highlight=find%20missing%20files#file

To save the baking cache for physics simulations see: [Can I save the baking cache?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7786/can-i-save-the-baking-cache) or [Is there a way to save a baked cloth simulation (in .blend file or to disc)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41623/is-there-a-way-to-save-a-baked-cloth-simulation-in-blend-file-or-to-disc/41624#41624)

> If the question is where to host a file for a question asked on this site please use:
>
> **https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/**

**Note**

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ can olny host .blend files (not zipped folders) used as part of questions and answers on this site, and they have to be smaller than 30MB. To share larger files or bundled content on zipped files there are numerous free or paid websites and services. But that part of the question is beyond the scope of this site, so do your own research.

Comment: How would I download the file to my hard drive I have a Mac desktop because when I go to place the folder in "blend-exchange" I can't find it :/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/