# My texture doesn't render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm working on Cycles render. I first added a material, went to color and inputted my texture image. I then unwrapped my object and applied the texture. When I press "shift z" to have a preview render, my object got the nice little texture. But then when I click on render, my texture doesn't show, it's not just plain white.

- shift z view

[image]

- Render view

[image]

Any ideas on what i can do to solve this problem?

Thank youu

[image]

[image]

This is my settings.

[image]
(I added the texture in this one)

Comment: It's really difficult to guess at what might be wrong. Can you add some screenshots of your node setup and/or render settings? If you don't have enough rep to post more images, just add links in the comments, and we'll get someone to add them to your post for you.

Comment: Did you hide the texture from render view?

Comment: What do you mean hide the texture from render view.. where is the option to enable it, in case I have enabled it by accident. thank you

Comment: I used motion tracking, so when I clicked on "setup tracking scene" the compositing was done automatically, so I don't think that that is where is the problem.

Comment: can you upload your file? Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: In the file I uploaded, for some reason my texture disappeared, it turned to purple..

Comment: Images used in blender are not saved as part of the file unless you "pack them" https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This is not the right answer.

This is a common confusion that I wish Blender would clarify. Making a texture work in the viewport is not necessarily the same as making it work in the render.

The short answer is: you have to plug UV coordinates into the Vector slot of your texture node. If you have more than one UV Map, you have to do a bit of trickery (which is not at all obvious) to choose which UV map you plug in.

[image]

[Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/texture_coordinate.html)

To further the confusion, it's quite possible (and not terribly difficult) to make your object use a completely different image and UV map in the viewport than it does in the render.

Comment: Hello Matt, in shader nodes, I added a texture coordinate and linked "UV" to the vector of my image texture but the result was the same. I also tried to assign the object, but nothing changed. You can try it yourself with my blender file I shared. I might have done something wrong. Do you have any other ideas on what causes the problem? thank you for your repsonse by the way

Comment: Interesting... I'll check it out!

Comment: Any findings Matt?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I haven't gotten to this yet. I will, I promise ;-)

Comment: A okay, that's okay. I'll wait.

Comment: I'm really not sure what might be going on with your setup. I'll edit my answer to include details of what worked for me.

Comment: Never mind... I figured it out. There's something wrong with your compositing setup. Stand by...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a compositing problem, but I'm not as familiar with compositing, so I'm not 100% sure what's going on.

I got it working by turning off the layer mask and adding the paper guy to BOTH the foreground and background layers. Then it works, without having to change anything else.