# Emitter Particles Not seen in Render

Tags: rendering, particles

I am trying to achieve a falling snow look, and I have an emitter set, but when rendered it will not show (the snow), just the planes (emitters) as shown below

[image: As you can see, I have a particle animation happening]

[image: But if I choose to render it, I cannot see the particles in the render]

To clear things up, I want it to be a falling snow animation, and those are the snowflakes for me. (the planes are just emitters (all are glued to be one object))

Comment: What are the particles set to render as and what render engine are you using?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your particles or your textures or render settings. Consider sharing your .blend file (with the images used as textures [packed into the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853)) so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: If you don't have an object/group set for the particles, they won't show at all in Cycles. Make sure to set up an object for them (e.g. a simple Icosphere). Further you can turn off the plane(s) by unchecking "Emitter" under the particle's "Render" tab.