# Placing mesh in the scene renders it white

Tags: node-editor, tracking

[image: Viewport, a cuboid placed in front of the real wooden box]

[image: when rendered, it makes that area white]

As you can see in the render, that area is white, where the mesh cuboid was placed. It's in second layer.

Comment: Presumably you're doing some compositing to combine the background image with the render? If so, please include the node setup you are using for compositing or, if you are not doing the compositing in blender, describe how you are doing it.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project or your textures or render settings. Consider sharing your .blend file (with the images used as textures [packed into the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853)) so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: yes, the problem was in composting nodes! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[image]Problem was in composting nodes, modifying the default nodes that are created after setting up tracking scene solved the problem.