# Particle checkered fur?

Tags: modeling, particles, hair

I'm having trouble with getting hair right. I'm making a ushanka and am using the particle system for adding fur, but it isn't putting hair in certain places (it's not the normals), heres a few examples[image: Checkered look] I know, rough, but im trying to get the fur right.[image: that damned checkered look] i have the emission coming out of the verts, interpolated children. uniform, endpoint and random are set to 0.01 and the length and threshold are 0.5. Also, there is no kink... I might abandon the hair/fur all together because it was supposed to be a cartoon look.

Comment: Have you tried emitting from the faces?  Do you have "Use Modifier Stack" checked (in case you are using a subsurf)?

Comment: Add a screenshot of Modifier Stack, looks like you have different subsurf settings for view and render

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project, particles, textures or render settings. Consider sharing your .blend file (with the images used as textures [packed into the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853)) so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.