# Pixelated textures in Blender Cycles Render

Tags: texturing, uv, game-engine, rigging, uv-image-editor

My model is almost ready for the demo I'm building, but I ran into another problem. I'm following this tutorial on Youtube by BornCG and made it to 9:05 when I started to put textures on top of the materials I placed on the model. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NlvgMYZgaY

When I plug in the diffuse node into the mix shader, pikachu's face turns white--like it does for BornCG in the video. But, when I plug the bottom image texture's alpha slot to the mix shader's grey port, the face stays white.

[image]

Also, my facial textures that I made for the pikachu model get pixelated when I bring them into blender. I used Photoshop CS to make the facial textures and turned them into PNGs. How can I fix this?

Edit: I found part of the problem and fixed it. The textures now have an alpha channel added to them, but the textures still get pixelated when I bring them into Blender. There's still the issue with the white background that gets added to them when brought into blender.

Comment: Does your image have an alpha channel?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I find out?

Comment: What do you mean by pixelation in this case? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. Please explain how you unwrapped the model.  Consider sharing your .blend file (with the images used as textures [packed into the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853)) so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: How is game engine related to your question then?

Comment: By "pixelation", do you mean eyes turning square shape instead of being round?