# What are these white splotches on my smoke render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I can't figure out why my purple smoke is rendering (cycles) with these white splotches. Does anyone have any insight? It has very simple material nodes, so I doubt that is the issue here, but I've never used smoke before so I have no idea where to even begin "debugging" it. Thanks.

[image: Render]

[image: Nodes]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project or your textures or render settings. Consider sharing your .blend file (with the images used as textures [packed into the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853)) so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. My domain was too small and the white was where the smoke was touching the “walls” of it.