# Problems rendering character eye

Tags: rendering

[image][image][image: this is how his eyes are supposed to look].hi im super noob with Blender. I modelled a simple character and when I render this character the body mesh shows up all right, but the eyes are completely blacked out instead of white with small black pupils.___=====+++++ I did search around for a few days straight and feels like im just going in circles. I went through the outliner, im really pretty useless with the node window but I did open that as well and look around. tried some other parenting tricks I thought might help, no dice.however, to make the eyes appear I went through object view, went to the modifiers tab and closed the targets for the eyes, this would make the eyeballs appear in the render but they didnt really follow the armature at all, so thats not what I want.  any suggestions I would definitely appreciate it.
heres the most recent version or .blend file [image]*^&&&7&997^&&(^(^&^&&^^&(^(&(&&^^&9

Comment: We need more information. How did you model the eye? What kind of material/textures are on it? show us the blend file, or at least a lot of screenshots.

Comment: theres no textures. the eyes are in two parts each inner eye and outer eye. 4 spheres. with a shrink wrap modifier and control bones. I dont know how to upload .blend files. I can send the file email, just to check out

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project or your textures or render settings. Consider sharing your .blend file (with the images used as textures [packed into the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853)) so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.