# Gray edge at the edges of texture when using alpha transparency

Tags: transparency

[image]

I try to make a tree model and apply alpha on the leaves, but somehow the shadow of the leaves form some sort of transparent masking like the image shown, what is causing the problem?

Comment: Open GL viewport may not show more than one bit alpha for unselected objects. If selected you should see alpha treated correctly but underlying alpha objects will still only be 1 bit.

Comment: Please make the title of your question specific to what you are asking, not just the general topic.

Comment: To get an answer you need to supply more information. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to reformulate your question. Some of the things we can't guess: What is the original image texture like? How did you set the alpha channel? How did you set the material you are using on the mesh? What render engine are you using (cycles or  blender internal)? What does the mesh you are using look like? Please add images that help us understand what you've done.

Comment: Consider sharing your .blend file (with the images used as textures [packed into the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853)) so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.