# Reflections are displayed nicely in preview, but not in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm running into a strange situation in Blender, where reflections show up nicely in Preview, but not in the final render (using Cycles). What could be the cause of this?

Preview:
[image]

Render:
[image]

here are my settings for Cycles:
[image]

and my blue, glossy material:
[image]

Is there some settings I'm forgetting about?

Here's the file:
[image]

Comment: not sure why this is, under "light paths" try changing the drop down to "Full Global Illumination" and see if that fixes anything. If so, then you may not have had enough light bounces. If not try changes the clamp direct and indirect to higher numbers (around 15)

Comment: Check also if there's anywhere lamp available for preview render but not final one.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but it didn't help. This is still a mystery to me... I added a .blend file, in case that would help solve this problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When sharing your .blend file please [pack the images used as textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853)

Comment: Oops, sorry about that (and thanks for letting me know)! in this particular case, we are only missing a colored texture (the blue shade), but (I hope) this doesn't change the reflection issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the simplify option in the scene-tab (at the bottom  of my screenshot).
simply disable it and you're good to go. you can also set the "AO bounces render" to 0 if you want to use other options of the simplifier (simplify subdivisions etc.). This option limits all non-diffuse bounces (0 = no limit)

[image]