# My model renders pink

Tags: rendering, animation

When I try to render an animation, the render result of the model looks like this...
[image]

And then when I render the animation for a bit, the process makes it glitchy, looking like this:
[image]

What do I do to match the animation up with the model render??[image]

Comment: Pink usually means that the texture is not available. Was the texture moved to a different place, a different folder?

Comment: @cegaton is't it strange that in the rendered preview the texture is shown?

Comment: can you detail a bit how you create materials for this object? can you show the nodes setup?

Comment: @m.ardito on the second image textured view is shown, which is very different. In any case without knowing how the materials are created, or if the images used as texture are linking correctly to the file is hard to tell. Pink  is a missing texture (unavailable or mapped incorrectly)

Comment: @FIREANDICEANDICE Consider sharing your .blend file (with the images used as textures [packed into the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853)), so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: Blender tells it's doing sequence render on the second image which probably means there are some images/clips in the Sequence editor, could it be the reason? (and character pose there differs, like it loses rig connection) As another thing to check, do you render animation on the same computer as static image? Though for now this is in general only guesses without a file and/or more details

Comment: I think @MrZak is on the right track. The fact that is happening on an animation might mean that the texture could be set to use an image sequence, but there are no more frames to load, or have the range of frames to  use has not been set correctly.