# Rendering the scene causes models' geometry to break

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I don't really know how else to explain it, but whenever I render my scene the models break with some of the geometry being rendered and some of it not.

Link to the .blend file [image][image: Image before render.] [image: Image after render.]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project or your textures or render settings. Consider sharing your .blend file (with the images used as textures [packed into the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853)) so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: You're not rendering your scene. You're just looking at it in rendered view mode, which is just a low-resolution indication of what the finished render might look like. Hit F12.

Comment: @cegaton It says the file is too big to fit in giantcowfilms :/

Comment: make a simplified version that shows the issue and upload that

Comment: I added the link

Comment: After downloading and opening the file, the 3d stereo model seems to be rendering ok, as far as I can tell, or at least without the problems depicted in your second screenshot?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's my hardware then

Comment: It is rendering ok for me too. But I've noticed the rendering feature set was "experimental".

Comment: @lemon I switched it off of experimental and it works! Looks like I won't be able to use bump maps, but at least it renders now! Thanks!

Comment: A thing you can try if not already done: update your gpu driver