# Squares caused by reflected area light

Tags: rendering, light

[image]

There are squares in my pictures. I do not know how or why this happens. Anyone who has experienced such problems?

First i tough it could be the denoise that made the squares, then I tought it could be collision between the lights or maybe the texture from the table. 
I have now tried to render without the denoise, I have removed the light from the candle and moved the table. I still can`t figure out what makes the squares. Same results every time.

[image]

I remove gloss from the lamps in the background (bookcase). It removed the squares, but I want the gloss on the table. Any way around this?

I now know that the problem is from the area lamp in the bookcase. 
When I turn the gloss off, the problem with the squares are gone, but I want the gloss though. 
So I remove the whiskey glass and glass that is in the bookcase. I remove the emissive from the spotlights and turn down the strength from the area lamps. But I still get the squares. 
I tried a different angle, but the results remains the same.

Comment: Not sure why, but they seem to only appear as a reflection of the lights in the bookcase. The reflection of the candle and windows are fine. Check the setting for the bookcase lights.

Comment: Perhaps not related, but there also seems to be something semi-transparent on the empty shelf of the bookcase. This may be right in the path of the reflected rays.

Comment: I remove gloss from the lamps in the background (bookcase). It removed the squares, but I want the gloss on the table. Not sure how to get around this. Guess I just have to try and fail with settings.

Comment: Try to increase number of Bouncesin render settings. Or even try Transparency, Max and Min.

Comment: Can you share a simplified version of the file, just with the light and the table (with the images used as textures [packed into the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853))?.  You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: I will give u the file soon. Have to get my son to sleep first :P

Comment: It happens on the newest blender file>blender-2.79-d59c2d1 with the new compiler. Happens when I use the GPU and CPU at the same time when rendering. Dident happent when I just used CPU.

Comment: What kind of GPU?

Comment: Nvidia gtx 1060 6GB

Answer (score 5):

Finally!

[image]

I had to increase the size of the area of the arealamp. i was set to 2mm or something. So the area was to small and messed up the light.

[image]

Want to give my thanks to Bfoot for helping me out! :D

Now I just have to redo every change I made to correct this :P

Comment: I tried to help. Perhaps just encouraged you to look further until you figured it out yourself. Congrats!