# Why are random white gaps will appearing in this texture?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

[image: The problem Images]

[image: The reddit conversation]

I tried getting help on r/blender to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Hi. If possible, please extract any *relevant* information from that reddit screenshot and include it as text (I think people may find that easier to read). Also, for blend files, please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ which is our official unofficial blend hosting site ([pack images beforehand](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82963/how-do-you-share-a-blender-file/82965#82965)). Thanks.

Comment: @RayMairlot Pretty much all information on that reddit screenshot is relevant. Also, I've added the .blend file.

Comment: Set the image texture node interpolation to "closest". The issue is due to uv map very near to some texture parts, but with "closest" should do it.

Comment: @lemon That worked, thanks for the help.

Comment: On official 2.80.75 no white gaps with even with linear extrapolation. https://imgur.com/0F71Ibs