# no material on my unwraped n texture painted mesh

Tags: materials, texture-painting

I have prepared a texture painting[image: in texture paint] for my apple and stem, but in layout mode, while I try to call the texture png in material properties, it doesn't give the material to the stem. I don't know why.
[image: in lay out mode-material properties]

Comment: Can you share the file? Please pack the texture as described here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82963/how-do-you-share-a-blender-file

Comment: solved.checked every thing n found out that I have written the name with Turkish keyboard.I renamed the file in English and it got solved.
thanks alot.