# Fire collision object

Tags: collision, fire

I am working in EEVEE and I set up a fire simulation. I am trying to figure out though, is there a way to have my fire wrap around an object? I need it to collide with what is above it and wrap around the sides...

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard task:

- add to your scene (domain and flow) one FLUID of type "EFFECTOR"
- simulate and check if the result is ok

Please keep in mind that a plane as "EFFECTOR" could not be correctly read by the simulation engine. Go with a cube or similar to be sure the simulation works.

Comment: Wow! That's awesome! Thank you so much for your help in this. That worked perfectly.

Comment: upvote and choose as preferred answer, thanks

Comment: Would you be able to tell me why my flame is appearing in front of my object? It is rendering over an object that is in front of it...

Comment: can you share the blend file or the screenshot?

Comment: I'm not sure how to upload a screenshot, but does this work? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PbT09EYoAeE2QX1JeCFXS8KA2ueJB0Qf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82963/how-do-you-share-a-blender-file

Comment: After doing that, the blender file is still a bit too large. Would you mind if i sent you a .blend file with Google Drive?

Comment: @Sandaldo - Here is  a download link for WeTransfer -https://wetransfer.com/downloads/06fbe6253e5dedcaffbfe5aa6dee778820200526002901/1fe97f074ce62e6cf89c4146f37c8eed20200526002901/404030

Comment: render crashes: you want the fire to stay inside the car?

Comment: Yes, but coming out of the windows  I do have it inside, but it is rendering over it for some reason. We're you able to view that image?

Comment: try to flip the normal of the EFFECTOR mesh to INSIDE (ALT N > recalculate inside)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108482/discussion-between-sanbaldo-and-henry-keller).