# The Perspective view is weird. I am in solid mode and I still only have outlines of the objects

Tags: 3d-view

Well it might be a bug, it might be an odd function of Blender too. I am not really sure. The weird view only appears when in 'free view' in perspective mode. (The view where you gan orbit around your scene with the middle mouse button) The problem does not appear in orthografic view, in camera view, in rendered; shading and wireframe view and in the views from top, the side, bottom etc. (Also orthografic)
Second weird thing is, I cant select any of the objects with a single mouse click. I now have to use the circle selector or draw the selection box.
The grid in the viewport disappeared too.

I do not know if I clicked something wrom or used a 'bad' keyboard shortcut or if it really is a bug. I just want to get this dumb piece of garbage out of my viewport.

This picture shows the bugged view. Just as I said. In all the other view modes and in the camera etc. it is just fine.

[image: issue preview]

[Download `.blend` file](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1xs1yI6emYbp8mixUIEXqIs28m_RPK3YQ&export=download)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your viewport goes haywire is because of the viewport's [Clip Start/End](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/properties/sidebar.html?highlight=clip%20start%20end#dview-view-clip) values which you set to crazy amounts.
To give you an idea, your largest object is 2 000 meters (2 kilometers) wide, yet your viewport is set to render stuff up to 100 000 meters (100 kilometers) away.
And you also stuff close up to 1 nanometer from your viewpoint, that's 0,001 millimeters!
A sheet of paper is about 100,000 nanometers thick, a strand of human DNA  is 2.5 nanometers in diameter. You really don't need those clipping values.

In most cases you shouldn't set the Clip Start below 0.001 (1 millimeter). Even that value is rarely needed, and it's only when you need to be really close to something, like when you modelize something of a few millimeters. On a large scene like that, you probably do not even need to set it under its default value: 0.1 m (10 centimeters)

As for the End Clip, it is way too large and will lead to rendering & performances issues. Unless you need to set your camera on one end of your map and be able to see everything up to the opposite end, you don't need more than 1000 m (1 kilometer).

Just a before/after comparison:

#### **crazy clipping values**

[image: crazy clipping values]

#### **normal clipping values**

[image: normal clipping values]

Comment: Alt + Z toggles the X-Ray mode but now the materials are ghosty. I think that one should be the x-ray because everything is half-opaque. But if I press Alt + Z again, everything just gets grey like before and I only can see the outlines... I really dont know what the heck caused this mess...

Comment: Then in solid mode, check your shading options (the arrow icon at the right of voew modes icons), maybe there's something weird here.

Comment: Well I have no idea what could be wrong there. I tried unticking everything by its own and it did not change anything...

Comment: Oh well... Apparently the shading view is also a bit bugyy, since all the meshes are half x-rayed too. I am pretty sure that is not what it is supposed to look.

Comment: It's not just a matter of checkboxes, besides it's not really a good idea to toggle everything without knowing how things work. Please show a screenshot of your shading settings. Or share your original .blend file so we can dig in

Comment: I am kind of new to asking questions on stackexchange. If you can explain how I can add more files, I can upload whatever is needed.

Comment: Edit your original post, add screenshots using the editor. Send your .blend file as a url. See this page for further instructions on how to send .blend files: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/53447

Comment: I found the problem and edited my original post. Please mark it as an answer to your topic if it solves it well.

Comment: Ok I really appreciate the help. I think it was just a matter of the lower clipping distance. That solved it. But I am not sure how it got so far down. I am sure that I di not put it that low. And apparently 10.000 on the upper limit is enough for my scene. I will keep that in mind when I encounter a problem like that again. Thank you very much for your time. :)