# How do I make a displacement modifier affect multiple objects?

Tags: modifiers, displacement

[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][1]][1]I've ripped this model out of a game, a character that is made up of multiple objects . I want to 3d print it , but since its from a game it doesn't have detail in the mesh , but in a displacement map , but since I want to 3d print it the detail needs to be in the mesh . now the legs , body and arms are different objects but there uv wrapped on one texture.

The displacement map is just one image for arms , legs and body , but I need to have the displacement modifier treat arms , legs and body as one object . Why I cant just join the objects together using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> ?

because the displacement map is made for the way that the objects are uv wrapped and joining them together would destroy the uv wrapp and thus make the displacement map useless.

[image]

Update:https:[image]
I put the original nrm file in as well

Comment: Consider sharing your .blend file (with the images used as textures 
[packed into the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853)) 
so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part 
of your question.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=aBb6r2Zs" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/aBb6r2Zs/)                                                                                                                                                                    Note:This is not finished I plan on ading clothes and posing it

Comment: The displacement map should be in the texures section

Comment: The texture is still not in the blend. Before you upload you must pack the texture and save the file.

Comment: I did at least I think... I'll just aply the texure to a default cube

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=qOKqzmzR" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/qOKqzmzR/)

Comment: You still need to pack it. The file location is currently set to `//..\..\Downloads\Wii U - The Legend of Zelda Breath of the Wild - Link\link_skin_nrm_DISP.jpg` Only your computer can access that location.

Comment: In the upper left of image editor, there should be a dropdown labeled image. Click that and find the button that says "pack."

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=EMrJRAY8" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/EMrJRAY8/)

Comment: Ok, idk what you're not getting here. That last link was a default scene.

Comment: no it isnt I loaded it up and it worked fine

Comment: You're right. fsr the first download must've been corrupted.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=rKesSgDg" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/rKesSgDg/)

Comment: Ok, that one's good, but there are some issues with what you are trying to do. The displacement map isn't consistent across the fingers and around seams which would be a pain to fix. I think you would be better off using it as a bump map, which is what it was likely intended for.

Comment: @gamefreakmilo please add any future new information such as images, updated blend, etc directly into the body of your question as an [edit]. You are always able to edit your posts. Please also read the [tour], there is some useful info there :) thanks

Comment: It originally was normal map . I read that you can't make those part of the mesh . if so please tell me how

Answer (score 2):

The different parts of the body have different UV-Maps.
As you can see in this image, when I join them, I get 3 UV-Maps
[image]
(At the rights side)

You can solve this problem, when you Name them the same before mergin.
Then you get this result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks I'll try that

Comment: so put them in the same vertex group? I don't entirely understand what you mean.

Comment: You name the Uv-maps the same before you merg them

Comment: Under the shape keys (which are under the vertex goup) you find Uv-Maps

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a lot

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUllU.png

Comment: @HISEROD said the displacement map wasn't made to be a displacement map wich is true so I guess im going to have to somehow make the normal map a part of the mesh . the reason I didnt do that is because there is no documentation about that... I thought it was inpossible , but apperently it is so please tell me how