# Boolean builds the shape of my cube inside of the mesh I am trying to cut the hole in

Tags: modeling, modifiers

What I seem to be having issues with is cutting the final 2 windows into the building using the Boolean Modifier. I have completed the same operation for the other windows with ease and had no issues with the process. With the last 2 windows on the wall when I use the boolean to cut I get a strange result where it basically builds the shape of my cube inside of the mesh I am trying to cut the hole in.

[image]

I have tried to read up on possible issues that can cause something like this. I am assuming the issue is because the wall is not manifold, but I do really know how to correct that if it is even the problem.  I have played with normals, deleted all the edges I can, merged vertices, I have even thought to pull that particular wall away from the model to see if anything on the interior of the face would be an issue and I cannot come up with anything.

let me know if you need to see anything more and I will gladly post it.*

[image]

Comment: Consider sharing your .blend file (with the images used as textures 
[packed into the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/1853))
so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at 
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then **paste the 
resulting link** as part of your original question.

Comment: Since you seem quite new to blender if you don't mind I'm going to try cleaning up some parts of your mesh for you, and leave some helpful tips for dealing with such topology in future.

Comment: That would be great. I would like as much information as I can get. Maybe seeing my mistakes will be helpful. Thank you