# Particles render in viewport but do not render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles, eevee-render-engine, osx

I am new at blender and trying to play with particles but it doesn't work when I render ( try as png and avi and nothing). I already tried several things mentioned in this community, but nothing worked (render as object, showing emitter. I already have the new version of blender 2.91.2 for mac, but that didn't solve either.Can anybody help me?
[image]

[image]

Comment: You could add some screenshots of your settings or even share your file

Comment: Hi Emir, Thank you! Put it above somehow I cannot upload the file or picture here,tell me if you need anything else!

Comment: try to bake the animation (even if it seems it's already baked). For more help share the blend file, thanks

Comment: I already bake it but it didn't solve it.I do I share the file here ( sorry silly question I am not seeing where)?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82963/how-do-you-share-a-blender-file

Comment: Thank you! It is already in the post, is just an experiment nothing special is jus to see how it works , but it didn't :(

Comment: @CristinaCabrita Not sure what you are trying to do, but you have a "Camera" under the object Instance for the particles... As far as i know, you can not render a camera as an object, but if you swtch that to something like a sphere instance, that worked correctly

Comment: Hi @Emir, Thank you can you show me with a print screen ? Thank you

Comment: @CristinaCabrita https://imgur.com/a/gyvSYgi

Comment: Hi @Emir thank you, it didn't work :( .I am using Macosx could it be some bug...

Comment: same happen with other file , there is something in the render settings but I cannot find what, is the other file. And thank you in avance [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=dEAlk6yG" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/dEAlk6yG/)