# Shadows from box projected texture appearing in the wrong places

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, shadows, procedural

I'm working on a semi-procedural planet generator, and the clouds are made using a seamless clouds texture set to box project, but for some reason their shadows are appearing in the wrong places. Does anyone know a way to fix this?

[image: clouds with incorrect shadows]

[image]

When a flat projection is used, the shadows are how I expect them to be (but the texture is warped because it's not UV mapped)
[image]

Using a greater-than node after the texture makes the issue even more clear:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should share with an [edit] what your result *should be*. All you have mentioned is that what you have is not what you expect.

Comment: I did, in the third image - But now I edited to make it more clear. But also I think it's pretty obvious, even if you ignore that 3rd image... the shadows are very clearly in the wrong places.

Comment: can you please share the file (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82963/how-do-you-share-a-blender-file) so we can check the setup of your objects?

Comment: I uploaded it to google drive - here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jmS5fxEgbWy8-gM_hqwkJfoOeNaKcRdO/view?usp=sharing