# My space potatoes are playing up in renders

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

On the left my render preview depicts the asteroids as intended and on the right the actual render.

I am not using compositing.

I am using the FZRandomizer 2.2 (https://fruitzeus.gumroad.com/l/aWSEM) addon to create generative art and I believe it's causing the issue somehow as the renders are showing up fine before running the script.

Was wondering if anyone might be able to recognise and identify the issue off-hand.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11PR0HzzKdQQbXdlqXYuzvunlMRfcpcVc/view?usp=sharing)

[image: blurry space potatoes]

Comment: In the future you should use [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82963/how-do-you-share-a-blender-file) for sharing blend files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have figured out the answer myself. All modifiers must be applied before running the FZRandomizer script.