# Rotations in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this setup: (I'd add the blend file but I don't know how :( ... )

[image]
[image]

[image]
The Nodes Modifier is on the Cube on 0,0,0.
The Constraints of the Empty are on the Cylinder (Pointer)

The Idea is to visualize a Raycast by the Mesh Line along the face normal of the Pointer.
In this position this is fine but if I rotate the Pointer the line rotates but at a smaller amount, then it snaps, simply strange behavior.

I recognized too: If I rotate the Pointer for 90 degree around Y I'd expect to show Pi/4 on
the Object Info Rotation output but it shows Pi/2

Any Idea what I'm getting wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: Blender Version 3.6.0

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/15795

Answer (score 0):

:D ... stupid me :D

I had only to ask: "What is a Vector?"
Well, a vector is .... a direction.

... and without a starting point originating at 0,0,0
So I have to rotate at 0,0,0 and afterwards to move the result to the face to simulate the face normal.
One finding: see the minus at the value for the Multiply Node. Normals seem to point TOWARDS the face in Blender.
[image]

Due to the issue with the Object Info Node I'll do some investigations and probably file some Bug(s). The Rotation output is showing double the rotation and the Math Node shows for all trigonometric functions the result for half their input.

Many thanks for the link how to share a .blend file :)