# need help baking

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I am (relavitly) new to Blender. For months now, I've been trying to figure out how to bake this particual lighting into my scene. But despite help from the developer of the Blosm plug-in, I'm at the end of my rope. So as per his suggestion, I'm asking for help here.

I'm trying to  download landscapes using the blosm plug-in. Once downloaded I want to add some custom lighting to give my scene some ambiance. But crucially, I need to be able to bake in the lighting in .glb format.

I am able to do this with all the objects I want, but no matter what I do I can't get the lighting to bake to the trees properly.

The trees I want to bake are the trees downloaded from open streetmap. Now here the thing: as long as I don't bake the lighting everything exports no problem. But as soon as I try and bake lighting the trees simply don't work.

Now the weird thing is, if I open a new file in blender file, add a plane with a texture and then place the same trees I downloaded from open streetmap, bake and export the trees come out fine. So there is something in the way Blosm treats the trees, or the terrain that makes exporting the trees something I simplly can't figure out.

I have made the file available here in my google drive if anyone wants to help. Any suggestions on how to figure this out would be apprepciated. Thank you.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f_X_GoEWbKDi7RIVHZNE7cUNzYSYVmeC/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Your drive file has limited access. Try sharing your blend file with this method it's alot easier to manage for everyone. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82965/53513

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)