Oblique object Numpad view problem
I have an oblique object that is NOT in the center of the 3D viewport. How can I have a front, side and a top view with Numpad 1, 3 and 7 like with an object in the 3D viewport center ?

(Not a period(. ) or slash(/) issue).

Pressing Alt+MMB on the object will center the view to the clicked area so the numbpad views and camera rotation use that as a reference if that's what you mean

Thanks for your response ! Alt and middle mouse button doesn't work ! @Cornivius

Can you show a picture of the object?

This view is with Numpad 3. I want it to be aligned with a z-axis and vertical

Do you mean that the object is rotated and you want the view to alight to the object's rotation? If so, with the object selected, press Shift+NumPad to alight the view to it. (Pressing 5 after to go into isometric view)

Thanks again. It doesn't work. Here is a picture of Shift and NumPad 1 (object selected):

Can you share the file?
The problem might be that the view will align first with the objects Origin. You'll have to press Shift+Drag with middle mouse button to put the geometry of it in focus.
Or, if you don't mind changing the origin, select the Object and go to the drop down menu Object->Set Origin->Origin to Geometry

Sorry, how do you attach a file ? @Cornivius

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82963/how-do-you-share-a-blender-file

Do you want the object to be aligned with an axis (i.e. rotate the object) because in one comment you said "I want it to be aligned with a z-axis and vertical"? Or do you want the view aligned with the normals of a face? For the latter you need to select a face and then instead of using Numpad 1, 3 or 7 press Shift + Numpad 1, 3 or 7. However, it might automatically switch to Perspective view instead of Orthographic (it is displayed in the top left of the viewport which view you are in). To switch back to orthographic you have to press Numpad 5.

Thanks for your response but it doesn't work shift and Numpad 1, 3 or 7 ! Actually, I want something like the 11:28 AM 6/17/2024 in France picture without having to move the object to the World Origin like I just did !
